# Acer Aspire T3 710 Ignores Boot Order

Tags: boot, system-installation, uefi, acer

Just bought a new Acer Aspire T3 710. It comes with Windows 10, but I had asked the store and they said it could install Ubuntu. Got it loaded up and plugged in my USB to install Ubuntu (new download from the site). But, Acer keeps ignoring the boot order and opening Windows again. I have done the F12 and the delete keys trying to change the boot order. It is not working.

Two days later and I am now unable to even get Windows back, says there is an error with Windows when I try to recover. I can not get Windows to load from the USB or DVD backups I have for Win10 or Win7.

I did find someone else online who had this problem and must have resolved it by making BIOS changes. http://www.canbike.org/information-technology/acer-uefi-boot-from-cddvd-axc-605-er30.html Still could not get my USB or DVD to boot. Then found someone who changed the boot filter so it is set to legacy instead of UEFI.  This left me with an error "Reboot and select proper boot device or insert boot media in select media and press any key". But, it still would not pick up my Ubuntu install from either the DVD or the USB drive.

I have changed the boot order, multiple times. I tried leaving the desktop shut down overnight before trying again.

This afternoon I phoned Acer and tech support there looked up the desktop and said it is possible to install Linux on it, depending on which Linux I was using. He said they do ship a few Linux computers with Ubuntu and that I should be able to install it if I find out more information online, etc. He did not offer any real help because, of course, no one actually supports Linux no matter what they tell you when you are holding your credit card to buy anything.

Tomorrow I am exchanging this desktop for another the same. Maybe starting fresh will be better. I still very much want to get Ubuntu as the OS. I do not need Windows on the hard drive at all. (I kept my old desktop, an HP which does not allow the OS to be changed from Windows). The whole plan with buying a new desktop was to use Ubuntu again. I had it running on an older Acer and loved it. I've been missing it ever since.

I really need some help, please. I don't want to try all the same ideas again and end up with another desktop which now won't load any OS.

I don't think it would make any difference, but I am using a 2 port KVM switch between the 2 desktops. Set up and runs without trouble.

Comment: Acer has unique requirement of setting UEFI password and then enabling "Trust" on Ubuntu/grub .efi files from inside UEFI. Acer Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot
Acer Aspire E 15 Downgrade to older UEFI, password & trust (ACPI issues?)
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2298380&p=13403062#post13403062
Also make sure you have newest UEFI from Acer. Some older models needed newest, I would expect new system to be ok, but best to check.

Comment: Thank you. I will cross my fingers and toes and try that. Other than the difference of F12 vs. F2 I think everything else would be about the same on a desktop or laptop. I will wish myself luck. ;)

Comment: You do need to install in UEFI boot mode, not CSM/Legacy/BIOS. And depending on video card/chip may need other/additional boot parameters. With UEFI you should always be able to directly boot Windows from UEFI boot menu. But to dual boot must have Windows fast start up off.  Grub only boots working/not hibernated Windows. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions